# Calculate Surface with GJK and EPA

Tags: algorithm

I am looking for a way to calculate the contact area between a face and a Sphere.

I think the GJK algorithm is good beginning. Because he say whether or not the two objects collide or not.

The Epa algorithm give the depth of collision.

And now, how to get the surface (area) in contact?

Comment: You might be better off with a [clipping algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)) or a polyhedron intersection algorithm.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. It could be the good way, is it useful to combine it with raytracing? So I can compute the surface of every polygon in contact with my sphere